# Не переведена строка при удалении вопроса, на который уже дан ответ

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, удаление-вопросов

Без комментариев

[image: Скриншот]

> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so
>   deprives future readers of this knowledge. See "I've thought better
>   of my question; can I delete it?" for alternatives to
>   deletion.

Comment: Вроде перевели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без понятия, где сейчас добавлять переводы.

В траде: https://ru.traducir.win/string/10991

В трансе: `f9039c99102036a6b7ecb47cfd2e86ec`.

И там, и там добавил перевод:

> Мы не рекомендуем удалять вопросы, на которые даны ответы. Это лишит
>   будущих читателей знаний по описанной проблеме. Почитайте "Я
>   переосмыслил свой вопрос; как его удалить?" для нахождения
>   альтернативы удалению.

Comment: Вроде, в транзифекс больше не надо ходить, да и вообще нельзя что ли

Comment: we need a reviewer to approve the suggestion before it lands in Transifex and then to the codebase (there are 30 suggestions awaiting a reviewer). If you have any questions about traducir, I'd be happy to answer them :) also, if there are pains I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @g3rv4 first non-diamond reviewer wants a button named "Edit & Approve" (also known as "Copy from suggestion to new suggestion") :)

Comment: feel free to [create an issue](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues) so that we can iron out those details and see who wants to work on it :) it sounds like a great addition